# How to make the ScrollView scrollabe for the imageview and textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make my activity scrollabe only for the ImageView and TextView in? I can only make the ImageView scrollabe but not with the text. This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="HJÆLP......"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="suggest"
    android:id="@+id/suggest"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="rate"
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/suggest"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/suggest" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"

        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/description" />


    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_weight="9"
android:text="description"
android:id="@+id/description"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_above="@id/image"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It's the last TextView (with id: description) I want it to be below the ImageView and both have to be in the ScrollView. Now I only have the ImageView in it, and it's too large.

Comment: Right now your textview is outside of your scrollView, as scrollView can only have one child, you should put both inside a linearLayout for example

Comment: Just keep in mind that **ScrollView can host only one child view**. So take both `UI` in `LinearLayout` and add that layout to `ScrollView`.

Comment: So I've to take everything in `ScrollView`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#4b14b1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="HJÆLP......"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="suggest"
        android:id="@+id/suggest"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="rate"
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/suggest"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/suggest" />



        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:layout_above="@+id/suggest"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/description" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:text="description"
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_above="@id/image"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: The ScrollView is at the buttom of the layout

Comment: Is the buttons `suggest` and `rate` in the ScrollView? I only want the ImageView and textView (descrption) in the ScrollView

Comment: suggest and rate  are not in scrollview. they fix on the bottom

Comment: I'm going to sleep .Bye.

Comment: Why isn't scrollable?

Comment: Didnt.'t you see the description?

Comment: if textview and imageview 's sumheight is less than the space they can get.the scrollview will not scrollable. Try add height of textview. Bye.

Comment: If you can see it .Why do you need it can scroll?